# Using apriori algorithm for market basket analysis

Tags: self-study, terminology, apriori

While I was studying  the formulation of  market basket analysis problem in the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) in the chapter **unsupervised learning**, I came through the following statement:

> The Apriori algorithm requires only one pass over the data for each
>   value of T ( K ), which is crucial since we assume the data cannot be
>   fitted into a computer’s main memory.  If the data are sufficiently
>   sparse (or if the threshold t is high enough), then the process will
>   terminate in reasonable time even for huge data sets.

where, T(K) is the support of item-set K.

The statement

> The Apriori algorithm requires only one pass over the data for each
>   value of T ( K )

is not making any sense to me. Since this algorithm involves many repetition then **why are they talking about "only one pass"? What does mean by "pass" here?** **How  is T(k) "crucial" here?**

And **what does mean by the phrase** ?

> data are sufficiently sparse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of the apriori algorithm is that if an item is very rare by itself, it cannot be a part of a larger itemset that is common.  Ie, if there are only 1 of {bananas}, there cannot be 10 of {bananas, milk}. So, if you are looking for frequent itemsets (eg, >2) of size 2, you might as well just ignore anything with {bananas}. (This is actually not realistic, bananas are one of the most commonly purchased items.)

It's a bit tricky to imagine this algorithm, but the attached picture makes it much clear.  You can see from this picture that each scan removes itemsets that are rare on each **pass (sweep through the data and check the freq of each istemset, deleting ones with frequency lower than threshold)**.  So, it scans the full dataset once for each size of itemset, but doesn't have to scan the entire set of combinations of the prior itemsets because some itemsets were removed at each pass.

The **threshold for frequency** is very important.  If the threshold for frequency is 100, then you might remove most of the candidate itemsets in the very first pass, and the next scans become very efficient.  If it is 0, you remove nothing, and each scan requires a pass through all of the combinations of the prior itemsets.

If the data is **sparse** (ie, many items have low counts), then you end up eliminating a lot of potential itemsets in the very first passes (of course, this depends on the threshold).

K is an itemset, and T(K) is the frequency of the itemset.  The text says `The Apriori algorithm requires only one pass over the data for each value of | K |`, not T(K). |K| is the cardinality of K, so the number of items.  So it only requires one pass per |K|.  Ie, |{bananas, bread}| =2.  It only requires one pass for the set of 2 item itemsets.

[image: *]

- https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~zaiane/courses/cmput499/slides/Lect10/sld054.htm

Comment: Thanks Sir for answer. I get you. But I am not able to understand the language of the book that I have written in question above. Would you explain those statements a little bit?

Comment: What does mean by this statement "The Apriori algorithm requires only one pass over the data for each value of T ( K )"

Comment: edited @ironman , I think the book is different that the quote

Comment: now it's clear to me